# Dictionary of father son names with options for user and outputs name of son, father, or grandfather

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make this file into two dictionary to access with the input of the user and I am completely lost. Sad to say I have been working on this for a couple of weeks now. I have the file read and and know how to set up the options for input, just not how to get a certain name based off of what the user option and name is.

Here is my code thus far:

```
sonfather = {}
fatherson = {}
names = open('names.dat', 'r')
sonfather = names.read().split(',')

print sonfather

print "Father/Son Finder"
print "0 - Quit"
print "1 - Find a Father"
print "2 - Find a Grandfather"
print "3 - Find a Son"
print "4 - Find a Grandson"
print "5 - List of names"

control = ""
while control != "quit":
    choice = input("Enter your choice here: ")
    if choice == 0:
        control = "quit"
    elif choice == 1:
        print input("Enter the name of the son :")
```

Comment: It would a  little hard to see what you're trying to accomplish by just this. Can you provide the input and expected output?

Comment: the input would be say the user wants to find a father. He/she would then be prompted to type the name of the son. With the name of the son it would return the name of the father. When I run the print of sonfather I get: ['john:fred', ' fred:bill', ' sam:tony', ' jim:william', ' william:mark', ' krager:holdyn', ' danny:brett', ' danny:issak', ' danny:jack', ' blasen:zade', ' david:dieter', ' adam:seth', ' seth:enos']

Comment: Not that, the file input.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: If the option is finding a father and the user inputs "john", it would display "fred". Likewise if the user was looking for the grandfather and was asked to type in the son and they typed in "john", it would display "bill".

Comment: @alKid you can tell what his input is by his print message in his comment above yours. Also user3019652 , i think you just arent understanding what exactly a dictionary is. gimme a minute ill prepare an answer.

Comment: I am confused on a lot of this.haha

Answer (score 0):

```
names = open('names.dat', 'r')
sonfather = names.read().split(',')
print sonfather
```

you have to understand what type an object is, in order to properly use anything dictionary related to it. because you arent going to get dictionary type things unless its a dictionary type.

`sonfather` at the time of `print` is a list. it is a list that contains strings.

you need to do SOMETHING to that list, that will "change" it to a dictionary. just because it has `"KEY:VALUE"` it does not mean its a dictionary. its a string.

SO for starters, you may want to just split each of them at the colon.

```
sonfather = [x.split(':') for x in sonfather]
```

this `[x for x in blabla]` thing is list comprehension, it might be a lil bit advanced... but it does the same thing as this:

```
new_sonfather = []
for item in sonfather:
    new_sonfather.append(item.split(":"))
sonfather = new_sonfather
```

this iterates over each item in `sonfather` replacing it (note for advanced pythonistas: i know not really...) with a list in this form `"son:father"` becomes `['son','father']`

THEN you have something that looks like this

`sonfather = [['son1','father1'],['son2','father2'],['son3','father3'],['son4','father4']]`

this is ALMOST where you want it to be.

THEN it gets super magical up in here.

convert that sucker to a dictionary from here

```
son_father_dictionary = dict(sonfather)
```

aww snaps son.

AT THIS POINT it `son_father_dictionary` is a TRUE official card carrying member of the dictionary club.

so if you were to do something crazy like:

```
print(son_father_dictionary['son1'])
```

the output would be `father1`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. I have been stuck on the first part for so long. But how then do you output the name of a grandfather from the name of a father? Say the user wants to know the name of the grandfather from the input name of ['son1'].

Comment: you can do that a couple of different ways. the easiest (yet most difficult to read) would be to just make another dictionary the same way, probably called `father_grandfather_dictionary` and then go `print(father_grandfather_dictionary[son_father_dictionary['son1']])`. You are going to have way better luck and functionality if you created an object that has properties "father" and "son" and then some methods to determine who is next in lineage (and add son/father) But that route would involve a complete reworking of your entire code. plus you would need to learn how to work classes/objects...

Comment: The way I am trying to do it just isn't working. son = raw_input("Enter the name of the son: ")
            if son in son_father_dictionary:
                the_father = son_father[son]